# Is there an expression for $i, j, k \in \left\{1,\, 2,\, 3\right\}$ with $i \neq j \neq k$?

Tags: index-notation, kronecker-delta

I want to make a statement where $i, j, k \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$ but $i \neq j \neq k$ and assumed there'd be an equivalent of
$$
\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0, & i = j \\ 1, & i \neq j \end{cases}
$$

This led me to wonder if there is some other generalization?

Comment: I would probably use the notation $\delta^*_{ijk}:= \prod_{\text{Sym}} \delta_{ab}$. I haven't seen a standard way to write what you're looking for otherwise... Perhaps some notation from Cech cohomology could be used? I fear it would confuse a reader though.

Comment: Your definition of $δ_{ij}$ is reversed from the Kronecker delta: you have $δ_{ii} = 0$, Kronecker has $δ_{ii} = 1$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks @AndersKaseorg -- I was thinking Levi-Civita & recalling it as the generalization of $\delta_{ij}$ (although now I'm unsure why that would be the case..). Editing to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute value of the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

$\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is 1 for (i,j,k) being cyclic permutations of (1,2,3) and -1 for (i,j,k) being cyclic permutations of (1,3,2), and $0$ if there are repetitions.

Comment: wow - cannot believe I missed that one. Thank you.